# Публикация приложения VisualStudio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

При публикации приложения в VisualStudio 2013 (правой кнопкой по проекту -> опубликовать) есть ли возможность исключить некоторые изменения?  Например, опубликовать последнюю возвращенную в main-ветку версию проекта, без учета последующих локальных изменений?